Noise in gravitational wave detections
I'm reading a paper (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.49.2658) in order to understand the use of Fisher Matrix in gravitational wave detection. I'm a bit confused with the assumptions they do about the noise in the detector. In section 2.A., they say that the noise will have both Gaussian and non-Gaussian components. They restrict the analysis to Gaussian noise only.
Then they define the noise curve:
$S_n(f) = \infty$ if $f<10$ Hz and $S_n(f) = S_0${$(f_0/f)^4 + 2[1+ (f/f_0)^2 ]$} if $f>10$ Hz.
Later in the paper in section 2.B., they define a noise weighted inner product and then say that probability for the noise to have some realisation $n_0(t)$ is
$p(n=n_0) \propto e^{-(n_0|n_0)/2}$.
I don't understand a couple of things:

What is the meaning of 'realisation'?
I'm not able to understand what do they mean by Gaussian noise? Do they mean that at each frequency, the distribution of noise is Gaussian?



What is the meaning of 'realisation'?

It is the value you would get upon detection or observation. i.e., another way of saying that given the probability distribution $p(n)$, then the probability of measuring (realizing) a value $n_0$ is $p(n_0)$.

Gaussian noise? Do they mean that at each frequency, the distribution of noise is Gaussian?

Yes. The signal noise is Gaussian, meaning it has a probability density function consistent with a normal distribution. The paper refers to the function $$p(\beta) \propto e^{-\beta^2}$$ which has the form of a normal (Gaussian) distribution given by the general form $$f(x)\propto e^{-x^2}$$

So I'm still a bit confused as to what we actually mean by p(n). So p(n) is a Gaussian with mean zero and some variance, right? And when we say we measure a value n_0 of noise, does that mean that we have measured it for a particular frequency? Or what does it mean exactly?

AFAIK, Gaussian noise means that the time series $x_i$ follows a Gaussian distribution with zero correlation, so that the power spectrum is uniform (white noise).
